# ! LaTeX Error: File `12pt.cls' not found

Tags: pdftex, winedt

**Here's my code:**

```
\documentclass{12pt}{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym}
\begin{document}
\title{Assignment-1}
\date{\today}
\author{xyz}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{ODE}
Hello
\subsection{Maths}
\subsubsection{Hello}
\section{Paragraph-2}
\subsection{stats}
$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
\end{document}
```

**The error I keep getting:**

> Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "one.tex"
>   Startup Folder: C:\Users\xyz\Desktop
>
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930)
>   entering extended mode
>   (one.tex
>   LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>
> ! LaTeX Error: File `12pt.cls' not found.
>
> Type X to quit or  to proceed,
>   or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:

*I am new to this, please answer in a detailed manner.*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It is preferible to use `\[ ... \]` for displayed equations instead of  `$$ ... $$`: see this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: Could be your installation of MiKTeX is faulty. Because you are using an older version have you considered to update your MiKTeX? I recommend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix here should be simple. Use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

instead of

```
\documentclass{12pt}{article}
```

Note the use of `[12pt]` as an *optional* argument to the `\documentclass` command, rather than your supply of `{12pt}` - a mandatory argument.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Now I am getting a warning saying AcroRd32.exe "C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\one.pdf"

Comment: @M.M.: That sounds like a setup issue with your editor, not (La)TeX.